# Which index is useful for below query?

Tags: mongodb

```
"filter" : {
            "a" : null,
            "$or" : [
                {
                    "b" : {
                        "$c" : {
                            "k" : "",
                            "v" : true
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "d" : {
                        "$in" : [
                            "value"
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "e" : {
                        "$in" : [
                            "value"
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "f" : {
                        "$exists" : true
                    },
                    "$nor" : [
                        {
                            "b" : {
                                "$c" : {
                                    "k" : "",
                                    "v.read" : false
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "b" : {
                                "$c" : {
                                    "k" : "",
                                    "v.read" : false
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "b" : {
                                "$c" : {
                                    "k" : {
                                        "$in" : [ ]
                                    },
                                    "v.read" : false
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "b" : {
                        "$c" : {
                            "k" : "",
                            "v.read" : true
                        }
                    },
                    "$nor" : [
                        {
                            "b" : {
                                "$c" : {
                                    "k" : "",
                                    "v.read" : false
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "b" : {
                                "$c" : {
                                    "k" : {
                                        "$in" : [ ]
                                    },
                                    "v.read" : false
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "b" : {
                        "$c" : {
                            "k" : {
                                "$in" : [ ]
                            },
                            "v.read" : true
                        }
                    },
                    "$nor" : [
                        {
                            "b" : {
                                "$c" : {
                                    "k" : "",
                                    "v.read" : false
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "b" : {
                        "$c" : {
                            "k" : "",
                            "v.read" : true
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            "g" : null,
            "h" : "",
            "i" : "",
            "j" : true
        },
        "sort" : {
            "k" : -1
        }
```

Comment: please explain what you want

Comment: This query has too many conditions. Instead of trying to find a weird and overcomplicated index, I would suggest to factor out the match logic to a specific field and see if a combined index with that field and `k` works.

The above strategy is not that optimal if you have a write intensive application.